# How large numbers are stored in registers

Tags: assembly, bigint, extended-precision

This is a basic question but say I want to multiply 3 numbers together that are in registers $t2, $t3, and $t4. Hypothetically speaking, assume each register can only hold 8 bits and when we multiply the three numbers together and the result may be bigger than 8 bits. If it is bigger than 8 bits, how would the result be stored in register $t0 if each register can only hold 8 bits?

Comment: You've just discovered *arithmetic overflow* -- hit your favourite search engine.

Comment: Different ISAs do different things here, you might get both halves (so two outputs), maybe only the low half, maybe something else..

Comment: @harold thank you that's what I wanted to touch on. If i do get two outputs does it store one output in one register and the other output in another register? Is it done simultaneously?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually CPUs have some kind of an instruction that multiplies two registers and gives a result twice as large, spread across multiple registers. This is necessary to implement extended precision arithmetic.

For example on amd64, to multiply two 64-bit numbers and get a 128-bit result you would do:

```
mov rax, qword ptr [t2]
mul qword ptr [t3]
; the result is now in rdx : rax
mov qword ptr [result], rax
mov qword ptr [result + 8], rdx
```

To multipliy three 64-bit numbers and get a 192-bit result you would have to implement extended precision multiplication by multiplying the relevant parts as above and summing them together.

Comment: Not familiar with the AMD64 ISA but that makes sense. So how is the result stored in rdx and rax? Im guessing the assembler or compiler automatically does it for you?

Comment: @deryl: No, it's how the `mul` instruction works. It takes the value in `rax`, multiplies it by the operand, then stores the result in the `rdx:rax` pair. And amd64, aka x64, is kind of a 64-bit extension of x86, which is what all 64-bit Intel processors run.

Comment: @deryl: x86: http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/MUL.html, and same for the one-operand form of IMUL.  MIPS has dedicated HI and LO registers for holding full-multiply results, and special movhi and movlo instructions for copying the results into general-purpose registers, IIRC.  ARM has separate 32x32 => 32b instructions (UMUL) and full-multiply UMULL, the latter taking 4 operands (2 input and 2 output).  Here's an example with C and asm output: https://godbolt.org/g/WlmkR9

Comment: @deryl: godbolt also has AVR gcc4.5.  AVR is an 8-bit RISC microcontroller, where registers really are 8 bits.  Unfortunately gcc just calls a library function for the equivalent function (with char and short): https://godbolt.org/g/j0xyUu

Answer (score 0):

In that specific case the arithmetic unit would set an [overflow flag](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overflow_flag)

Answer (score 0):

Nohow. This is well known **arithmetic overflow**.

Sometimes you can change the order of operators to avoid such overflow. F.e. instead `if (a + b > INT_MAX) ...` you can write `if (a > INT_MAX - b) ...` and so on.

Sometimes you should use `int64` instead of `int32`, or `double` instead of `float`.

And sometimes you should use big numbers library like [GMP](https://gmplib.org/).